# How to secure single page application with spring boot

Tags: angular, spring-boot, spring-security

I have a spring boot application that authenticate with keycloak (Single sign on) and is using Angular as front end.

I have only 1 index.html page which is the main page for the angular app, I need to make it secure but I am not sure how to do this

I followed this example:  [https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2017/05/25/easily-secure-your-spring-boot-applications-with-keycloak/](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-keycloak)

In the example, they have un-secure index.html page and when you click product link, it goes to spring controller and gets authenticated first against single sign on, then forward to a product page. I verified that and saw the principal being passed to controller.

The demo is using Thimeleaf framework, so the product page is under templates folder.

I am facing 2 issue

1) is I have one index.html page and I don't want the user to get to it at all unless authenticated.

2) when I trigger from the angular page a call to a REST controller it's performing it without authentication (principal is null in REST controller)

so my questions is 1) how can I force it to authenticate directly before I show the index.html

2) why there is no principal when the rest service is called and it's allowing it.

This is my application configuration class

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class InvoiceSearchApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(InvoiceSearchApplication.class, args);
    }


    @Configuration
    @EnableWebSecurity
    @ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = KeycloakSecurityComponents.class)
    class SecurityConfig extends KeycloakWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter
    {
        /**
         * Registers the KeycloakAuthenticationProvider with the authentication manager.
         */
        @Autowired
        public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
            KeycloakAuthenticationProvider keycloakAuthenticationProvider = keycloakAuthenticationProvider();
            keycloakAuthenticationProvider.setGrantedAuthoritiesMapper(new SimpleAuthorityMapper());
            auth.authenticationProvider(keycloakAuthenticationProvider);
        }

        /**
         * Defines the session authentication strategy.
         */
        @Bean
        @Override
        protected SessionAuthenticationStrategy sessionAuthenticationStrategy() {
            return new RegisterSessionAuthenticationStrategy(new SessionRegistryImpl());
        }

        @Bean
        public KeycloakConfigResolver KeycloakConfigResolver() {return new KeycloakSpringBootConfigResolver();}

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception
        {
            super.configure(http);
            http.cors().and().csrf().disable();
            http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/*").authenticated().anyRequest().permitAll()
             .antMatchers("/assets/*").permitAll()
             .antMatchers("/assets/img/*").permitAll() ;


        }
    }
```

I put the index.html under src/main/resources/static
and I put all css and js files under src/main/resources/static/assets.

That's why I added the

.antMatchers("/assets/*").permitAll()
                 .antMatchers("/assets/img/*").permitAll() ;

So it will load them, otherwise I will get 403 forbidden on the js files.

and this is my pom.xml

```xml
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>product-app</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>product-app</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <keycloak.version>3.1.0.Final</keycloak.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-freemarker</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
            <artifactId>keycloak-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-ws-core</artifactId>
        </dependency> 

       <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
             <version>3.9</version>
        </dependency>  

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.mail</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.keycloak.bom</groupId>
                <artifactId>keycloak-adapter-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${keycloak.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

application.properties

```
server.context-path = /invoiceSearch
keycloak.credentials.secret=${keycloak_credentials_secret}
keycloak.realm-key=${keycloak_realm_key}
keycloak.realm=${keycloak_realm}
keycloak.auth-server-url=${keycloak_auth_server_url}
keycloak.resource=${keycloak_resource}
keycloak.ssl-required = external
```

my index.html page:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Invoice Search </title>
   <base href="/invoiceSearch/">  
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/invoiceSearch/assets/img/mag_glass_icon.png">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/invoiceSearch/assets/styles.eb6a472291bbfc46890c.css"></head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/invoiceSearch/assets/runtime.cf9a0e7464e091b22929.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/invoiceSearch/assets/es2015-polyfills.bda95d5896422d031328.js" nomodule></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/invoiceSearch/assets/polyfills.8bbb231b43165d65d357.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/invoiceSearch/assets/scripts.03e042f1f102bf0e2ed8.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/invoiceSearch/assets/main.32b645cbed7ce5c0e94f.js"></script></body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot to unpack here. I'm not too familiar with keycloak, so I will speak more generically.

1. To prevent users from accessing index.html, it needs to be behind spring security, and authentication would have needed to have happened already. Assuming authentication does happen prior to the user getting the index.html page, you would need to have a spring security setup to handle that, or have a secure endpoint that returns the index.html page. The difficulty here is that a GET call for index.html has no easy way to pass an auth header token. For Angular apps, the optimal solution would be to use a reverse web proxy, to handle not only static content distribution, but user page refreshes, where you need to return the index.html page from angular routes (mysite/ng/route1)
2. This begs the question how your user is being marked as authenticated. I'm going to assume a token, as keycloak uses tokens with SSO. If that is the case, it means that you MUST pass that token back with each authenticated request, generally as an auth header with Bearer, or the spring application with keycloak will not know who your user is. Unless your index.html page really has confidential information on it, which I have to assume it does not, as your content is not secure, the best solution is to do this:

a. Leave index.html unsecured
b. On entry, check for a saved token, or handle SSO/OAuth using the keycloak auth endpoint. You have to get your user a token somehow....
c. Save the token in sessionStorage for page refresh safety.
d. add the token to the global html header configuration in angular.

You can also secure your angular routes based on user authentication status or role using auth guards, but keep in mind this isn't "real" security and is really more of a facade.

Comment: We're authenticating against LDAP in Keycloak, we're not sending a token. I just found out that the demo site is actually using a link in the html page to the spring controller "/products". When you click the link, the authentication is happening, because I can see the principal in the controller. But I am doing GET/POST to a controller and not a link. When this is done, it doesn't happen. I am getting 404 on Get and 403 on POST. if I make it a link (href) to controller, it gets there with the principal authenticated.